Sequences with periodic vs autoperiodic correlation
Many sequences commonly used in communications, such as Gold, Kasami, Zadoff-Chu, and Ipatov, are favored for their good periodic correlation properties, specifically their low or zero sidelobes. However, I've often heard claims that aperiodic correlations are considered "better" or more advantageous, and I wonder what the technical reasons behind this preference might be.
One possible reason for the widespread use of periodic correlation sequences in communications could be the relative ease of their construction. But I’m curious if there are specific technical advantages associated with periodic correlation that make it more suitable in certain scenarios.
I would greatly appreciate any recommendations for references that clearly explain the pros and cons of both periodic and aperiodic correlations.
-R

When you say "periodic", what exactly are you referring to? For example, in a Barker code, you repeat a number of subpulses (aka chips) each with a different phase. This is one sense of "periodic" but not usually a term used when describing a modulation since it may cause confusion vs other types of periodicity.

You are going to have to be specific as to what you mean by "periodic correlation" vs "aperiodic correlation."
